Quote about expecting robots to take our manual labour from us but now AI is taking our creativity instead?
I've seen somewhere an excellent quote, something along the lines of (very inexact wording):

I wanted the robots to do my manual chores for me so I could create art and poetry; now the AIs are creating art and poetry and I'm still doing manual chores.

I'm not the only one who remembers this quote, but I don't know the exact wording or source. Where does this come from?

I don't think it's the source of the quote you've stated here, but there's a tweet by Karl Sharro from May 15, 2023  which reads "Humans doing the hard jobs on minimum wage while the robots write poetry and paint is not the future I wanted" (Screenshot). From what I can tell this is the Tweet that started this genre of post on Twitter (which had not yet become X at that time).

In all seriousness: AI that reassembles bits in a computer is easy-peasy. AI with android mobility and dexterity to load/unload dishwashers, washers and dryers, that's  smart and dexterous enough to sort dirty laundry, bring it to the washing machine, load it, run it at the proper setting, put it in the dryer -- or lay it flat to dry -- and then fold + put on hangars everything,  then walk up and down stairs, know who room everything belongs to, opening dresser drawers, rearranging clothes, opening closets, etc is going to be Damned Impressive.  Not happening any time soon.

Possibly:

You know what the biggest problem with pushing all-things-AI is? Wrong direction.
I want AI to do my laundry and dishes so that I can do art and writing, not for AI to do my art and writing so that I can do my laundry and dishes.


By @AuthorJMac

Yep, that sounds like what I remember reading. Thanks!

The problem with the attitude is that AI and robots can do both. We've already had washing machines and dishwashers for decades.

This seems like a strange take, since I'm unclear how anything that has happened with AI would prevent one from making art or writing.

@DanielB It doesn't say "prevent", and certainly AI now claims to be able to do art and writing for us.
